# Using Viewport to create a mobile friendly version

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, viewport, mobile-webkit

I'm working on a site, but I want a mobile friendly version aswell. I'm a newbie to this.

Someone suggested I should use the following code, to which I can't find many relating question on here:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to implement it, and I know that cannot simply convert the whole page.

What I am requesting is some pointers on how I can reach my goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/ gives you an introduction to the various aspects of the viewport meta tag. For optimizations across a range of screen sizes, you probably want to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in combination with media queries (also covered in the article above).

Note that the Element Fusion tutorial you linked to uses semicolon delimiters between viewport values instead of commas - this is not correct. Be sure to use commas, like in your initial example :-)

Answer (score 4):

There are quite few posts about viewport. you simply put it between your head tags.
http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html might give you better idea.
Don't forget to use mobile doctype together with viewport.

For example

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, width=device-width" />
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found a good tutorial here which helped. http://www.elementfusion.com/tutorial-optimizing-your-website-for-mobile-devices

Should have deleted my question!

Comment: There is no good reason to use a mobile doctype together with viewport. You should be good with just using <!doctype html>

Comment: How did you come up with that @andreasbovens? mobile doctype is recommended doctype for mobile web sites. <!doctype html> is fine if you design for mobile safari though

Comment: It's not a W3C standard, you're needlessly limiting the amount of HTML you can use, and you have to serve it as application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml which triggers draconian error handling in case the XML is not well-formed. Hence, <!doctype html> does the job perfectly and works across mobile browsers (Opera, Safari, Firefox, Android, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I’m using iWeb 2011 with all its outdated configurations and of course with a relative width of 700px.

I’ve found this works with all devices without changing anything:

```
<meta name="viewport content="width=700=content=width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

This is my website:

http://theevolutionofreason.com/The_Evolution_Of_Reason.html

Take it for a spin with a resizer app. Or download Google’s viewport resizer app. (free), to show its visual compatibility with all devices

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/viewport-resizer/kapnjjcfcncngkadhpmijlkblpibdcgm

Also, check out my website’s “Element Source”.

Visit:Apple Support Communities Discussion
"iWeb viewport configuration"
https://discussions.apple.com/message/29393840?ac_cid=op123456#29393840